# Clojure: Trying to convert a hash-map into a string

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I am pretty new to Clojure and still trying to grasp the fundamentals. While experimenting, I had the following problem. I tried to make a nested map and convert this into a JSON Object without the use of an external library, but keep running into a wall. I was wondering if someone could guide / help me to get on the right track.

I want to thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and help me out.

I have the following hash-map in Clojure:

```
; Creating Hashmap
(def hashmap
  [
   { :Mineral-1 {
            :Mineral-name       {:value "Gold"}
            :Color              {:value "Golden"}
            :Weight             {:value 2324.23}
            :Count              {:value 203}
            :Price              {:value 20320.49}
            :DeliveryContainers {:value-1 {:value 1}
                                 :value-2 {:value 2}
                                 :value-3 {:value 3}}
            :Sold               {:value true}
            }
    }
   { :Mineral-2 {
              :Mineral-name       {:value "Silver"}
              :Color              {:value "Silvered"}
              :Weight             {:value 2313.23}
              :Count              {:value 425}
              :Price              {:value 12345.12}
              :DeliveryContainers {:value-1 {:value 4}
                                   :value-2 {:value 5}
                                   :value-3 {:value 6}}
              :Sold               {:value false}
              }
    }
   ]
)
```

And I am trying to convert it to the following string:

```
"
  [{
    "Minerals": [{
                  "Mineral-1": {
                                "Mineral-name": "Gold",
                                "Color": "Golden",
                                "Weight": 2324.23,
                                "Count": 203,
                                "Price": 20320.49,
                                "DeliveryContainers": [1, 2, 3]
                                },
                  "Mineral-2": {
                                "Mineral-name": "Silver",
                                "Color": "Silver",
                                "Weight": 2342.56,
                                "Count": 234,
                                "Price": 23123.23,
                                "DeliveryContainers": [4, 5, 6]
                                }
                  }]
    }]"
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use an external library for this? I don't think JSON export is included in the Clojure core library. But there is a good external library, [Cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire), to both parse and produce JSON.

Comment: Hello @Rulle, It is a challenge that I set up for myself, and I am trying to complete. I know there is an external library, but this is purely for educational purposes.

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and why did it not work?

Comment: While not part of the core, there is also https://github.com/clojure/data.json You can look at the sources there.  In particular, the definition of the `write` function which handles the general case.  If you meant the particular case of this particular map, then you can use `map` to (recursively) print out each key-value pair of the map.

Comment: @Rulle Thanks so munch for the time youre spending on me, really appreciate it. The thing I am mostly struggling with is iterating till the last array.

my code: https://pastebin.com/eHaiXasD

Comment: @dorab that unfortunately is the problem that I am currently facing. I am trying to read out the hash map but the (rest) function does not return any value back to me, and I am trying to figure out why. my code: pastebin.com/eHaiXasD

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you restrict yourself to a limited subset of Clojure structures, here is an example that you can use (if you excuse the poor formatting).

```clj
user> (def hmap
        [ { :Mineral-1 {
                        :Mineral-name       {:value "Gold"}
                        :Color              {:value "Golden"}
                        :Weight             {:value 2324.23}
                        :Count              {:value 203}
                        :Price              {:value 20320.49}
                        :DeliveryContainers {:value-1 {:value 1}
                                             :value-2 {:value 2}
                                             :value-3 {:value 3}}
                        :Sold               {:value true} } }
         { :Mineral-2 {
                       :Mineral-name       {:value "Silver"}
                       :Color              {:value "Silvered"}
                       :Weight             {:value 2313.23}
                       :Count              {:value 425}
                       :Price              {:value 12345.12}
                       :DeliveryContainers {:value-1 {:value 4}
                                            :value-2 {:value 5}
                                            :value-3 {:value 6}}
                       :Sold               {:value false} } } ])
#'user/hmap
user> (declare print-json) ; forward declaration
#'user/print-json
user> (defn print-json-map [x]
        (print "{ ")
        (run! (fn [[k v]]
                (print (str "\"" (name k) "\""))
                (print ": ")
                (print-json v))
              x)
        (println "}"))
#'user/print-json-map
user> (defn print-json-vec [x]
        (print "[ ")
        (run! #(print-json %) x)
        (println "]"))
#'user/print-json-vec
user> (defn print-json-prim [x]
        (cond (string? x) (print (str "\"" x "\""))
              (number? x) (print x)
              (boolean? x) (print x)
              :else (println "CANNOT HAPPEN")))
#'user/print-json-prim
user> (defn print-json [x]
        (cond (map? x) (print-json-map x)
              (vector? x) (print-json-vec x)
              :else (print-json-prim x)))
#'user/print-json
user> (print-json hmap)
[ { "Mineral-1": { "Mineral-name": { "value": "Gold"}
"Color": { "value": "Golden"}
"Weight": { "value": 2324.23}
"Count": { "value": 203}
"Price": { "value": 20320.49}
"DeliveryContainers": { "value-1": { "value": 1}
"value-2": { "value": 2}
"value-3": { "value": 3}
}
"Sold": { "value": true}
}
}
{ "Mineral-2": { "Mineral-name": { "value": "Silver"}
"Color": { "value": "Silvered"}
"Weight": { "value": 2313.23}
"Count": { "value": 425}
"Price": { "value": 12345.12}
"DeliveryContainers": { "value-1": { "value": 4}
"value-2": { "value": 5}
"value-3": { "value": 6}
}
"Sold": { "value": false}
}
}
]
nil
user>
```

Comment: Wrap this with `with-out-str` and you get a string instead.

Comment: What about *comma* separating array and map elements?

Comment: `(apply str (butlast (interleave values (repeat delimiter))))`

Comment: Hello @Dorab thank you so munch for all the help! I was wondering about your opinion about my code that I wrote: https://pastebin.com/ACrYsj9Z

Comment: Your solution looks good - for this case and for learning.  @Rulle You are correct that my solution needs the comma delimiters to be proper JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for educational purpose I made a solution using more of Clojure's build in language features:

```
(import '[clojure.lang Sequential Keyword Symbol])
(import '[java.util Map])
(defprotocol MyJSON
  (to-json [this]))

(def ^:dynamic *indent* 0)

(defmacro indent [& body]
  `(binding [*indent* (inc *indent*)] ~@body))

(def indent-size 2)

(defn indent-space []
  (apply str (repeat (* indent-size *indent*) " ")))

(defn comma-sep
  ([values] (comma-sep values ", "))
  ([values delim]
   (apply str (butlast (interleave values (repeat delim))))))

(extend-protocol MyJSON
  Boolean
  (to-json [this] (str this))
  String
  (to-json [this] this)
  Number
  (to-json [this] (str this))
  nil
  (to-json [_] "null")
  Keyword
  (to-json [this] (name this))
  Symbol
  (to-json [this] (name this))
  Sequential
  (to-json [this] (str "[" (comma-sep (map to-json this)) "]"))
  Map
  (to-json [this] (str "\n" (indent-space) "{\n"
                    (indent (comma-sep
                              (map (fn [[k v]] (str (indent-space) (to-json k) ": " (to-json v))) this)
                              ",\n"))
                    "\n"
                    (indent-space) "}" )))
```

Regarding `{:value "1"}`, which transforms "1", to  and `{:value-1 "1" :value-2 "2"}`, which transforms to `["1" "2"]`:
I suggest to do this transformation first and finally convert the transformed data to json.

Comment: Hello Hatatister! Thank you so munch for this, I actually managed to make my own implementation and I was wondering about your opinion.

https://pastebin.com/ACrYsj9Z

Comment: I like your usage of string/join. It is more idiomatic than my (butlast (interleave ...) function. Your solution is fine for your problem. If you want to build a more general solution: You are ignoring list, set and symbol values. Your `cond` statement works, but is not extensible. Protocols or multi methods would give you the ability to extend  json serialisation to more types. (E.g Inst, uuid, rationals, user-defined types). Your solution uses recursion (so does mine and dorabs, too). If you have heavily nested data structures, this could lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: It depends on your problem, if you need those features

Comment: I cannot see, that you are using indention and newlines for pretty printing. Should the output not be more like `{a: [flat, {nested: thing}, without], line: breaks}`. Again, if you do not need it, it is totally fine.